# Submit From with Enter key without refreshing the page in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to submit From (Textarea) values with Enter key and without refreshing the page. I also do not want to show the submit button. Using the code below, but on Enter, it refreshes the page. Help will be appreciated.

**Current Behaviour**

- Form can be submitted with Enter key but it refreshes the page.

**Required Behaviour**

- Submit the form with Enter Key without refreshing the page and adding the button element.

  ```
       import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';

       export const AppHomeFeedPage = () => {
           const [values, setValues] = useState(NewPostsInitialValues);
           const Avatar = UserAvatar
           const ref = useRef();

           function changeHandler (event) {
               setValues({
                   ...values,
                   [event.target.name]: event.target.value
               });
               console.log(values)
           }
           const onSubmitForm = (e) => {
               e.preventDefault();
               if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 'Enter') {
                   ref.current.submit();
               }
               let userId = values.userId;
               let userName = values.userName;
               let postText = values.postText;
               console.log(userId, userName, postText )

           }

           return(

                   <div className='AppHomePageContentContainer'>
                       <div className="AppMainContentWrapper">
                           <form className='NewPostForm' ref={ref} onKeyUp={onSubmitForm} tabIndex={0}>
                           <div className="NewPostCardContainer">
                               <div className="NewPostCardContainerWrapper">
                                   <div className="NewPostCardTopWrapper">
                                       <div className="NewPostCarUserAvatarContainer">
                                           <div className="NewPostCarUserAvatarWrapper">
                                               <img className='NewPostCarUserAvatar' src={Avatar} alt="user image"/>
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div className="NewPostCardInputContainer">
                                           <div className="NewPostCardInputWrapper">
                                       <textarea
                                           name='postText'
                                           className="NewPostTextArea"
                                           placeholder={`How's your Portfolio Today ?`}
                                           // id='quoteTypeLabelContainer'
                                           value={values.postText}
                                           onChange={changeHandler}

                                       />
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                           </form>

                       </div>

                   </div>
           )
       }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use `onSubmitForm` as an `onSubmit` listener instead of `onKeyUp`. Most browsers will treat pressing enter in a form as submit action.

i.e.

```
<form onSubmit{onSubmitForm} />
```

```
const onSubmitForm = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Since this is not a keyUp event, you don't need this part
  // if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 'Enter') {
  //   ref.current.submit();
  // }

  let userId = values.userId;
  let userName = values.userName;
  let postText = values.postText;
  console.log(userId, userName, postText)

  // HTTP request submit form, modify it depending on your need
  fetch('/api/form', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ userId, userName, postText })
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried, it does not submit, if I press enter without IF statement in "onSubmitForm", it goes to the next line on enter and do not detect the Enter Key at all.

Comment: I tried testing with INPUT instead of TextArea and it works perfectly, however, I need it to work with Textarea.

Comment: I don't think you will like that idea with text area. The reason you want to use the text area is to support multi-line text, but now you are preventing users to insert new lines. This contradicts the usage of the text area.

Comment: textarea break the line when reached assigned width without pressing enter, input, however, do not break-line and user cannot see what they typing after assigned width.